# Como criar aplicativos com banco de dados no phonegap?

Tags: apache-cordova

Eu estou tentando fazer um app para plataformas móveis, utilizando o phonegap. Nele são utilizados HTML5, CSS e JavaScript.

Eu preciso fazer um banco de dados para armazenar questões, mas não sei como posso fazer isso, alguém poderia me dar uma dica do que usar e como preparo um banco de dados?

Comment: Olá, boa tarde. O banco de dados que você precisa tem que rodar no celular ou remotamente em algum servidor ("nuvem")?

Comment: No celular mesmo

Answer (score 1):

De acordo com a [documentação da API de armazenamento de dados do Phone Gap](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/4.0.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html) você tem as seguintes opções para persistir localmente os dados de seu aplicativo:

- [LocalStorage](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/)
- [WebSQL](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webdatabase/)
- [IndexedDB](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/)
- [Plugins](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/)